# Breaking the for loop does not provide the correct output

Tags: r, for-loop

I fit three different `kemans` models to the iris data set. Then, I would like to compare their
rand index (RI) using the `for` loop. If the RI of a model is larger than the second one, then stop the loop and return the largest values of RI.

For example, if the `RI` of the first model is larger than the `RI` of the second model, then
break the `for` loop and provide the `RI` of the first model. In my example, the `RI` of the second model is larger than the third model. Hence, the `for` loop should break and provide me with the value of the second model `fit2$cluster`. When I run the model it returns me the number 1, which is the first model and it is not correct. If there is a way to return the name of the model would be even better. Any help, please?

Here is my try:

```
library(aricode)## contain the RI function
fit1 <- kmeans(iris[,-5], centers = 2)
fit2 <- kmeans(iris[,-5], centers = 3)
fit3 <- kmeans(iris[,-5], centers = 4)
fit <- list(fit1$cluster, fit2$cluster, fit3$cluster)
```

### Here is my for loop

```
for(i in seq_along(fit)){
   if (RI(fit[[i]], iris[,5]) > RI(fit[[i+1]], iris[,5])) break
    # x <- RI(fit[[i]], iris[,5])
 print(i)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only printing 1, exactly because `RI` of your second model is larger than the third model and for that, if condition satisfies in the 2nd iteration and the loop breaks before printing 2, therefore, you have only 1 printed, instead try this

```r
for(i in seq_along(fit)){
   if (RI(fit[[i]], iris[,5]) > RI(fit[[i+1]], iris[,5])) {
      print(i)
      break
     }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you want to `print`, you can only read it but can't do anything with it. Also `break` isn't needed, since you want to run the loop to the end.

Here we use model 1 as starting value and update it in every iteration.

```
w <- 1L
for (i in seq_along(fit)[-1L]) { 
  if (RI(fit[[i]], iris[, 5]) > RI(fit[[i - 1]], iris[, 5])) {
    w <- i
  } 
}
w
# [1] 2

RI(fit[[w]], iris[, 5]) 
# [1] 0.8797315
```

**Alternatively**, it would be much easier if `RI()` was `Vectorized`, so let's do it!

```
RIv <- Vectorize(RI, vectorize.args='c1')

RIv(fit, iris[, 5])
# [1] 0.7636689 0.8797315 0.8295302
```

To learn, which model has the larges value, we use `which.max`,

```
RIv(fit, iris[, 5]) |> which.max()
# [1] 2
```

to simply get the largest value, we pipe it into `max`,

```
RIv(fit, iris[, 5]) |> max()
# [1] 0.8797315
```

or all together:

```
RIv(fit, iris[, 5]) |> {\(.) {w=which.max(.); data.frame(model=w, value=.[w])}}()
#   model     value
# 1     2 0.8797315
```

Comment: +1 Thank you a lot for your great answer. I really learn a lot from it. However, I need to break the model because  I am working with complicated data/models, where I really need to stop the model at a specific condition.  Thanks again. Really appreciate your help.